# Localização errada API Google HTML

Tags: javascript, html5, google-maps, maps

Olá, estou tentando capturar a minha localização a partir da API do Google/com os recursos do novo HTML5.

Porém a minha latitude e longitude sempre dá esta que está incorreta, seja no computador ou mobile:

```
latitude: -23.550519899999998
longitude: -46.633309399999995
```

No celular já habilitei a localização via GPS mas mesmo assim ele ainda trás a incorreta, o que pode ser?

Segue código que estou utilizando:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p id="demo">Aceite para receber sua localização em Latitude e Longitude</p>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var apiGeolocationSuccess = function(position) {
                alert("API geolocation success!\n\nlat = " + position.coords.latitude + "\nlng = " + position.coords.longitude);
            };

            var tryAPIGeolocation = function() {
                $.post( "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=AIzaSyDCa1LUe1vOczX1hO_iGYgyo8p_jYuGOPU", function(success) {
                    apiGeolocationSuccess({coords: {latitude: success.location.lat, longitude: success.location.lng}});
              })
              .fail(function(err) {
                alert("API Geolocation error! \n\n"+err);
              });
            };

            var browserGeolocationSuccess = function(position) {
                alert("Browser geolocation success!\n\nlat = " + position.coords.latitude + "\nlng = " + position.coords.longitude);
            };

            var browserGeolocationFail = function(error) {
              switch (error.code) {
                case error.TIMEOUT:
                  alert("Browser geolocation error !\n\nTimeout.");
                  break;
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                  if(error.message.indexOf("Only secure origins are allowed") == 0) {
                    tryAPIGeolocation();
                  }
                  break;
                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                  alert("Browser geolocation error !\n\nPosition unavailable.");
                  break;
              }
            };

            var tryGeolocation = function() {
              if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                    browserGeolocationSuccess,
                  browserGeolocationFail,
                  {maximumAge: 50000, timeout: 20000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
              }
            };

            tryGeolocation();
        </script>
        <!--<script>
            $(function(){
                getLocation();
            });
            var x = $("#demo");
            function getLocation(){
                if(navigator.geolocation){
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
                } else {
                    x.text("O seu navegador não suporta Geolocalização.");
                }
            }
            function showPosition(position){
                //console.log("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +" Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
                x.text("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +" Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude)
            }
        </script>-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Segue abaixo como está vindo a resposta do codigo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Errada? essa localização é pra onde? muito distante de voce ?

Comment: Sim! Não sei se vc é de São paulo, mas eu estou em pinheiros e segundo as coordenadas, estou no centro, praça da sé. https://goo.gl/maps/gk2Eq1AgZix

Comment: Estranho mesmo. Executei o seu código aqui e deu a minha localização corretamente.

Comment: Já executei este código em três dispositivos diferentes e até mesmo dois scripts alternativos, mas a resposta é sempre a mesma! Sabem oq pode ser??

Comment: @jvbarsou pra mim também veio minha localização correta. Morumbi - SP. Ja tentou executar o script de outra localização?

Comment: @RafaelAugusto realizei alguns testes aqui fora do ambiente onde estou mas o range de proximidade ainda é mt perto e a resposta continua igual. Adicionei umas imagens na pergunta mostrando melhor como ele retorna pra mim. Até mesmo se eu clicar para buscar a localização diretamente no site do google maps ele me traz a praça da sé. Dei uma lida sobre e dizem que quando o maps nao te encontra, ele retorna a sé como "marco 0", pois sabe que vc esta em SP

Comment: engraçado, reencaminhei o link para um amigo que esta do outro lado de sp e retornou a mesma coisa. eu hospedei o link neste dominio, poderiam conferir? cdz.bz/geoLocation.html

Comment: A própria API do google não fornece esse dados com exatidão, de os Maps que trabalhei o Waze é que tem a menor margem de erro pra esse tipo de situação

Comment: @LuKsSys clicando no link ele apresentou a sua localização correta? cdz.bz/geoLocation.html

Comment: Apenad para questão nao morrer...Ajuda!?